# Create dynamic xml from properties file?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, rest, dynamic

I have decided to create dynamic xml as a response of my rest service.

Xml structure is defined in properties file it may change in future.

What will best approach to achieve this task.

Help me out with suggestions friends.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there an option to convert the properties file into an XSD ? If you have your xml template saved in a XSD, that will make life lot simpler. Let us know if that is possible.

Comment: Properties file contains the hierarchy of the xml.Let us take the scenario my xml has 5 elements like firstname,lastname,age,empid,salary.So each element has its position in properties file so i have read the postion of the element each time to form a xml.Eg : firstname as users/employee/firstname ,secondname users/employee/lastname like goes on.In future i may change the employee as users/employees/person so without code still i can get the different xml structure if i configured the structure in properties.I hope its clears.

Comment: Yes, you can move the same to an xsd. If you have a XML Schema Definition, then creaing the xml will be more standardized and robust. XSD itself being a XML, modifying it will be easier than modifying the properties file.

Comment: But enduser can't modify the xsd easily  right and to modify xsd technical knowledge is required.If it is property file any one can easily modify it just a key value pair text file . correct me if am wrong.

Comment: Maybe, can you provide a sample properties file content?

Comment: firstname.xml_payload_structure = "user_profile/user/firstname
lastname.xml_payload_structure = "user_profile/user/lastname
age.xml_payload_structure = "user_profile/user/age..

It may contain nested xml tags too.

Comment: Is it possible to have an empty xml file instead in your properties file like below:"<user_profile>
<user>
<firstname/>
<lastname/>
<age/>
</user>
</user_profile>" ... I think user should be able to modify this easily without any technical knowledge

Comment: Is dom is good to create dynamice xml or anything else is better than this ?

Comment: If the xml is small, then Dom is good. If the xml will not fit into your memory, then you need to think about streaming. Based on my understanding of your requirement, DOM should be fine for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to use the properties file for generating dynamic XML. If the client requirement is that you have to used that properties file. Else the recommended way is to use the XSD schema generation method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory to generate the XML output. You can read the XML structure from the property file as your requirement and can generate the output using the javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory.

Hope following code will helpful to you.

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
XMLOutputFactory xmlFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
XMLStreamWriter writer = xmlFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(stringWriter);

writer.writeStartDocument();
writer.writeStartElement(<<First element>>);
```

Comment: And how do you recommend, reading the properties file and getting the element names/hierarchies?

Comment: To avoid code change in future we decide to go with this approach.If it is not good suggest me better way.

Comment: firstname.xml_payload_structure = "user_profile/user/firstname
lastname.xml_payload_structure = "user_profile/user/lastname
age.xml_payload_structure = "user_profile/user/age..

It may contain nested xml tags too.

Comment: Sridhar, DOM will be good approach when the XML file is not large.  write huge amounts of data it is better to use SAX, SAX also provides higher performance.

Comment: Okay thanks.The code you mentioned above is SAX right?

Comment: It is StAX based implementation which comes with java 6.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using the Properties [propertyNames()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#stringPropertyNames%28%29) we will be getting the list of all the keys.
2. Using keys we can find the values.
3. Using this we can create a xml file using StringBuilder

For Example

`StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("<"+key+">");
sb.append("+value+");
sb.append("</"+key+">");`

After this write it to a file . Using FileOutputStream.java

Comment: You can load the properties file using

Comment: Yes but we are defining the structure alone in properties not values .

Comment: If the values are not there then its ok to have just the keys with out values

Comment: We are getting the structure of the xml from properties file.